# ¿Como puedo ir a un commit especifico y volverlo master?

Tags: git

Tengo errores en mi codigo y quisiera poder volver a un `commit` especifico y poder volverlo `master`, de que manera puedo hacerlo ?

este es mi `commit`

```
commit 70b0aecf7ee7bfb4864eab75e56ccd67426926f1
Author: emeery <jerrery@live.com.mx>
Date:   Tue Apr 3 23:48:28 2018 -0500

    cabecera estrategias
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero haz un

`git reset - - hard {commit}`

Una vez hecho el reset, para subirlo como máster debes forzar el push, puesto que en el remoto ya está subido unos niveles por encima de ese commit

```
Git push - - force origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

Con esto debe de funcionar:  `git reset --hard {id_commit}` luego  debes hacer push al tu repo: git `push -f <remote> <branch>`

Comment: Hola Mario, al tratar de subir mi código al repositorio con el comando git pull origin vuelvo a tener el código con errores o como puedo subir mi commit al repo una vez usando reset?

Comment: mariovzc si alguién agrega 70b0aecf7ee7bfb4864eab75e56ccd67426926f1 en lugar del id de su commit esto no funcionaría, especificalo como jakala o {id commit}